# Location jquery em nova guia

Tags: jquery

Como faço o **location** abaixo abrir em uma **nova guia**?

```
$(".mySlides").click(function(){

  let url = $(this).data('value');

  $(location).attr('href', url);

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não necessita JQUERY

```
$(".mySlides").click(function(){

 let url = $(this).data('value');
    window.open(url, '_blank');
}
```

Comment: Ok. Mas, e se eu quisesse usar jQuery. Existe uma forma de contornar isso?

Comment: Penso que nao, o jquery é feito pra simplificar se nao me engano, mas como podes ver esta situação jà é bem simples mas nao tenho a certeza a 100% que nao exista algo semelhante em JQUERY

Comment: Mas já está ótimo! Essa solução eu já conhecia. mas como você teve a boa vontade de ajudar, valeu o pontinho! Obrigado!